# How to compare two aggregates in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, aggregate-functions

I have a model `Car` with two hasMany relations `Seat` and `Cupholder` which I aggregate like this:

```php
Car::query()
    ->withCount('seats')
    ->withCount('cupholders')
```

resulting in

| id | make | seats_count | cupholders_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Supercar | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | Old one | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | Fancycar | 8 | 5 |

I want to build a query that shows all cars with less cupholders than seats.

Aggregates cannot be compared using `->where()` and using `->having()` I can only compare one aggregate to a static value or another column.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to compare aggregates is by left-joining them as sub queries like this:

```php
$sub = Car::query()
    ->withCount('seats')
    ->withCount('cupholders');

$query = Car::query()
    ->leftJoinSub($sub, 'sub', 'cars.id', '=', 'sub.id')
    ->addSelect('seats_count', 'cupholders_count')
    ->where('sub.cupholders_count', '<', 'sub.seats_count');
```

which results in

| id | make | seats_count | cupholders_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Old one | 4 | 3 |
| 3 | Fancycar | 8 | 5 |

Would love to see a better way to do this, though.